# how can I get yesterdays date in unix format in javascript?

Tags: javascript, flickr

I'm self-learning the REST concept and am playing with the Flickr API.  One of the parameters that Flickr requires is the `min_upload_date`, which is formatted in the Unix date format and looks like this in the example...

```
&min_upload_date=1199145600
```

I'd like to set the `min_upload_date` to the day before the current day, but I don't even know where to start with this.  I've found the `Date()` object in javascript and figured out how to set it equal to yesterday's date, but how do I convert it to the format that Flickr needs?

Thanks in advance for all your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

call [**`.getTime()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/Date/getTime) on the `Date` object you have:

```
"...&min_upload_date=" + (yesterday.getTime() / 1000)
```

Comment: @Jordan: see the `/ 1000` perhaps?

Comment: That's what the `/ 1000` is for